# NSAttributedString not displaying correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I want my UILabel to be able to split a long name into two lines and add the hyphen. Currently my code is like so :

```
let usernameX = profilePhoto.frame.size.width+horizontalMargin
let username = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: usernameX, y: (self.frame.size.height/2)-21, width: self.frame.size.width-usernameX-horizontalMargin, height: 42))
username.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
username.font = UIFont(name: "SFUIDisplay-Regular", size: 20)
username.minimumScaleFactor = 0.8
username.numberOfLines = 2
username.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.hyphenationFactor = 0.5
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Areallylongname", attributes: [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle])
```

However the label is only displaying `"Areally-"`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just a punt, but if you call `adjustFontSizeToFitWidth` after you set the font does that help?

Comment: however `42` is the ultimate answer in our universe, but it does not guarantee that two lines can fit in a container with that height, you probably need to calculate the correct _height_ value dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-check the height of superview of label.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing 42 as height is not the correct way to do it. You can calculate height of the label required dynamically and assign it. You can do it following way.

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Areallylongname", attributes: [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle, NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "SFUIDisplay-Regular", size: 20)])
var newFrame = attributedString.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(username.frame.size.width, 9999), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin , context: nil)
newFrame.origin.x = username.frame.origin.x
newFrame.origin.y = username.frame.origin.y
```

You can set the new frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`